# Symfony2 Unit Testing Compiler Passes

Tags: symfony, phpunit

Does anyone have any advice for how to unit test a Symfony2 `CompilerPassInterface::process()` instance?

In particular, the ones I want to test generally deal with tagged items, adding method calls to a "manager" service.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to test it in isolation, you'll have to mock the `ContainerBuilder`, and mock any service definition it returns.

That's usually quite annoying though. So I would tend to write an integration test instead. And in fact, that's what most of the compiler pass tests of symfony core do as well.

You would:

- Create an instance of `ContainerBuilder`
- Register some stub services
- Create the compiler pass
- Call `$pass->process($container);`
- Assert that the pass did its thing correctly

For an example of this, take a look at the [RemoveUnusedDefinitionsPassTest](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Tests/Compiler/RemoveUnusedDefinitionsPassTest.php).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I think testing it in true isolation would be ridiculously overkill, so integration testing is perfect.